# Creating Soap messages with objectTypes using SUDS library in Robot Framework

Tags: soap, robotframework, suds

i am struggling to create this part of the soap message using robot framework with SUDS library.

```
<ns1:Request>
    <ns0:ID objectType="SomeType">Value</ns0:ID>
</ns1:Request>
```

If i do like this, then i get all i need but not the objectType.

```
${object}=    Create Wsdl Object    ns19:RequestTypeSingle
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${object}    ID    1234
```

Output

```
  <ns1:Request>
    <ns0:ID>1234</ns0:ID>
  </ns1:Request>
```

If i check what my ns19:RequestTypeSingle wants i get this:

```
${object} = (RequestTypeSingle){
   ID = 
      (ID){
         _objectType = ""
      }
 }
```

"RequestTypeSingle" definition

```
<xs:complexType name="RequestTypeSingle">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" nillable="true">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
     <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="objectType" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So how can i declare this "(ID){_objectType = ""} with SUDS or some other?

Thanks to ombre42 this can be done like this (first question answered):

```
${req}=    Create WSDL Object    ns19:RequestTypeSingle    # may need namespace prefix here
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${req.ID}    _objectType    SomeType
```

(Continuing question).
How ever this will not set the value as i mentioned in my request example. It would seem that this kind of syntax would work but it did not. Any great ideas on this one?

This will give an error: "ValueError: Object must be a WSDL object (suds.sudsobject.Object)."

```
${req}=    Create WSDL Object    ns19:RequestTypeSingle    # may need namespace prefix here
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${req}    ID    1234
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${req.ID}    _objectType    SomeType
```

And this will overwrite the first _objectType definition.

```
${req}=    Create WSDL Object    ns19:RequestTypeSingle    # may need namespace prefix here
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${req.ID}    _objectType    SomeType
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${req}    ID    1234
```

What i mean by overwrite is that i get this:

```
  <ns1:Request>
    <ns0:ID>1234</ns0:ID>
  </ns1:Request>
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a value to property that is expressed as an XML attribute instead of an element, prefix the name with an underscore (why _objectType instead of objectType).

```
${req}=    Create WSDL Object    RequestTypeSingle    # may need namespace prefix here
Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${req.ID}    _objectType    SomeType
```

Comment: Did not work. "Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${object}    ID    ${id}" will create a inner element and that is not allowed. I need this in one line as RequestTypeSingle defines.

Comment: Added "RequestTypeSingle" definition

Comment: ID is not a complex type as I suspected. I have updated my answer accordingly. I was able to test the solution by taking your schema excerpt and including it in an existing WSDL. I was able to generate a request that looked like what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this. But still the value is not set. I updated my question (continuing question) defining my problem setting the objectType and value together. I thought this would not be "the" problem.

Comment: Not sure why you accepted this. From my research it seems the only way to solve this is to use a message plugin or patch Suds. Setting an attribute and element text on the same element is not possible with Suds 0.4 from what I can tell.

Comment: I accepted because it answered my first question (took it off now). But that was only partial answer since it did not provide the total answer to the problem (updated the question with continuing question). Seems you are the writer of the library so, if you are thinking about patching take "multiple attributes to wsdl object" in consideration. Great work by the way! I keep on trying to work this out and will post a answer here if I find any. For now this is a problem that forces me to use "Create Raw Soap Message" and catenation for 50% of the tests.