# Creating Soap messages with objectTypes using SUDS library and MessagePlugin in Robot Framework

Tags: soap, robotframework, suds

This a continuation for this questions: [Creating Soap messages with objectTypes using SUDS library in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567439/creating-soap-messages-with-objecttypes-using-suds-library-in-robot-framework)

In there it was determined that with RF SUDS it is not possible to create messages with objectTypes using SUDS alone. I would like to try the MessagePlugin approach, but unfortunately the information in documentation is not quite enough for me:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class _MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        body = context.envelope.getChild('Body')
        foo = body[0]
        foo.set('id', '12345')
        foo.set('version', '2.0')

class SudsLibraryExtensions(object):
    def attach_my_plugin(self):
        client = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SudsLibrary")._client()
        # prepend so SudsLibrary's plugin is left in place
        plugins = client.options.plugins
        if any(isinstance(x, _MyPlugin) for x in plugins):
            return
        plugins.insert(0, _MyPlugin())
        client.set_options(plugins=plugins)
```

Does anyone have any complete Robot example on how to use the above snippet? What should I be passing into marshalled as context? Do I need to call attach_my_plugin() at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general description of message plugins can be found in the [Suds documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#MessagePlugin). More detail is in the [class documentation](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.plugin.MessagePlugin-class.html). You do not call marshalled, suds does. To better understand how to implement the marshalled method, read up on the documentation for [Element](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.sax.element.Element-class.html). A suds plugin is essentially a listener. My example uses a public web service for demonstration.

Say your request looks like this:

```
...
<ns0:Body>
    <ns1:GetStatistics>
      <ns1:X>
...
```

But you need it to look like this:

```
....
<ns0:Body>
    <ns1:GetStatistics type="specialType">
      <ns1:X>
 ...
```

Here is a plugin that adds the type attribute to the GetStatistics element. This may be necessary when an element has child elements and attributes sent. Suds 0.4 does not support this, but it is valid SOAP. There may be a fork of Suds that does support this.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SudsLibrary
Library           c:/SudsLibraryExtensions.py

*** Test Cases ***
Message Plugin
    Create Soap Client    http://www.webservicex.net/Statistics.asmx?WSDL
    Attach My Plugin
    Set GetStats Type    specialType
    ${dbl array}=    Create Wsdl Object    ArrayOfDouble
    Append To List    ${dbl array.double}    2.0
    Append To List    ${dbl array.double}    3.0
    ${result}=    Call Soap Method    GetStatistics    ${dbl array}
    Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${result.Average}    2.5
```

Contents of c:/SudsLibraryExtensions.py:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class _MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):

    def __init__(self):
        self._type = 'defaultType'

    def marshalled(self, context):
        body = context.envelope.getChild('Body')
        call = body.getChild('GetStatistics')
        call.set('type', self._type)

    def set_getstats_type(self, value):
        self._type = value

class SudsLibraryExtensions(object):
    def attach_my_plugin(self):
        client = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SudsLibrary")._client()
        plugins = client.options.plugins
        if any(isinstance(x, _MyPlugin) for x in plugins):
            return
        # prepend so SudsLibrary's plugin is left in place
        plugins.insert(0, _MyPlugin())
        client.set_options(plugins=plugins)

    def set_getstats_type(self, value):
        self._get_plugin().set_getstats_type(value)

    def _get_plugin(self):
        client = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SudsLibrary")._client()
        plugins = client.options.plugins
        my_plugin = next((plugin for plugin in plugins if isinstance(plugin, _MyPlugin)), None)
        if my_plugin is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Plugin not found. Did you call Attach My Plugin?")
        return my_plugin
```

The type attribute will always be set so long as the plugin is attached with the keyword Attach My Plugin. There is a default type. To change the value of type, the keyword Set GetStats Type is used. Any type set will be used in all future requests until it is changed. The only reason that two classes are used here is to prevent "marshalled" from becoming an exposed keyword.